# Mysq Request | Get numbers from string in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a products table (products) with records:

```
id name
1  1969-1972 Chevrolet Small Block 
2  1971-1975 Chevrolet Small Block Fan Shroud
3  1964 Chevrolet Bumper Kit Complete
4  Chevrolet Clutch And Brake Pedal Assembly
...
```

Now I want to make request end extract first four numbers as a start date and chars from 6 to 9 as an end date.

So the result table will be:

```
id name                                             start end
 1  1969-1972 Chevrolet Small Block                 1969  1972
 2  1971-1975 Chevrolet Small Block Fan Shroud      1971  1975
 3  1964 Chevrolet Bumper Kit Complete              1964  null
 4  Chevrolet Clutch And Brake Pedal Assembly       null  null     
 ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. LEFT(name , 4) as start; 
 2. CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6, 4) AS UNSIGNED) as end;
```

Comment: so you found out yourself an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the query a bit more robust with some REGEXP matching e.g.

```
SELECT id, 
  name,
  CASE WHEN name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4}[ -]' THEN CAST(LEFT(name, 4) AS UNSIGNED)
  ELSE NULL
  END AS start,
  CASE WHEN name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{4} ' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6, 4) AS UNSIGNED)
  ELSE NULL
  END AS end
FROM products
```

Output:

```
id  name                                        start   end
1   1969-1972 Chevrolet Small Block             1969    1972
2   1971-1975 Chevrolet Small Block Fan Shroud  1971    1975
3   1964 Chevrolet Bumper Kit Complete          1964    (null)
4   Chevrolet Clutch And Brake Pedal Assembly   (null)  (null)
```

Or you can even remove the duplicate year information from the name if you wanted to:

```
SELECT id, 
  CASE WHEN name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{4} ' THEN SUBSTRING(name, 10)
       WHEN name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4} ' THEN SUBSTRING(name, 6)
       ELSE name 
  END AS name,
  CASE WHEN name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4}[ -]' THEN CAST(LEFT(name, 4) AS UNSIGNED)
  ELSE NULL
  END AS start,
  CASE WHEN name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{4} ' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6, 4) AS UNSIGNED)
  ELSE NULL
  END AS end
FROM products
```

Output:

```
id  name                                        start   end
1   Chevrolet Small Block                       1969    1972
2   Chevrolet Small Block Fan Shroud            1971    1975
3   Chevrolet Bumper Kit Complete               1964    (null)
4   Chevrolet Clutch And Brake Pedal Assembly   (null)  (null)
```